# How to initialise a three dimensional ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to initialise a three dimensional ruby array. For a two-dimensional array, I can do

```
a = Array.new(4){ Array.new(5, 0) }
```

so I have tried

```
a = Array.new(4) { Array.new(5, Array.new(6, 0)) }
```

but if I do `a[1][2][3] = 5`, it not only sets that element to `5`, it sets the corresponding element to `5` in other sub arrays i.e.

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that if you pass the value as an argument, you will get an array where each value refers to that same object. You do exactly that with:

```
Array.new(5, Array.new(6, 0))
```

---

You can use `Array#*`, i.e array multiplication instead:

```
[[[0] * 6] * 5] * 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same syntax (with a block instead of an argument : `Array.new(n){...}`) for all the dimensions.

```
a = Array.new(4) { Array.new(5) { Array.new(6, 0) } }
```

This way, your code will create 20 distincts `Array.new(6, 0)` sub-sub-arrays instead of replicating the same object 5 times.

```
require 'pp'
a = Array.new(4) { Array.new(5) { Array.new(6, 0) } }
a[1][2][3] = 5
pp a
# [[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
#  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
#  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
#  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked properly.

```
a=Array.new(4){ Array.new(5) { Array.new(6,0) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to initialize the elements of a multidimensional array of any dimension.<sup>1</sup>

**Code**

```
def init(n, *rest)
  rest.empty? ? Array.new(n, 0) : Array.new(n) { init(*rest) }
end
```

**Examples**

```
dims = [2, 3, 2]
a = init(*dims)
  #=> [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]

a[0][0][0] = 1
a #=> [[[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]

dims = [2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3]
a = init(*dims)

a.flatten.size
  #=> 288 (= 2*3*2*4*2*3)
a[0][0][0][0][0][0] = 1
a.flatten.count(1)
  #=> 1
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

Suppose, as in the example,

```
dims = [2, 3, 2]
```

Then

```
n, *rest = dims
  #=> [2, 3, 2]
n #=> 2
rest
  #=> [3, 2]
```

As `rest.empty? #=> false`, the method returns

```
Array.new(2) { init(*[3, 2]) } # (1)
  #=> [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

To obtain this result, we execute the block

```
{ init(*[3, 2]) }
```

for each of the two elements of the array being constructed. This requires us to compute `init([3, 2])` (same as `{ init(3, 2) }`), which is done as follows.

```
n, *rest = [3, 2]
  #=> [3, 2]
n #=> 3
rest
  #=> [2]
```

Again, as `rest.empty? #=> false`, we return

```
Array.new(3) { init(*[2]) } # (2)
  #=> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

to expression (1) above. For each of the 3 elements of this array we execute the block

```
{ init(*[2]) }
```

This requires us to compute `init([2])`, which is done as follows.

```
n, *rest = [2]
  #=> [2]
n #=> 2
rest 
  #=> []
```

This time, since `rest.empty? #=> true`, we compute and return

```
Array.new(2, 0)
  #=> [0, 0]
```

to expression (2) above.

<sup>1 Yes, there's no such thing as a "multidimensional array" in Ruby, but I expect readers to know what I mean. The alternative is something like "...of an array containing nested arrays of equal size with any number of levels of nesting", but even that is incomplete as it fails to exclude, for example, `[[1, [2,3]], [4,5]]`. It would be helpful if Ruby had a name for such objects.</sup>

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon in SO. Please add some explanation!